# Error while running https://github.com/PacktPublishing/TensorFlow-Machine-Learning-Projects/blob/master/Chapter11/ch-11.ipynb

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

The following code shown on [github repo](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/TensorFlow-Machine-Learning-Projects/blob/master/Chapter11/ch-11.ipynb) is shown as executed fine.
While trying to execute the same example with following stack :

- NumPy:1.14.3
- Pandas:0.23.4
- TensorFlow:1.12.0
- Keras:2.1.6-tf
- Python interpreter and version: 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  9 2018, 12:34:16)
- [GCC 7.3.0]

Getting following error :  -

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,0] = 570882 is not in [0, 235062)
     [[{{node ItemsEmbedding_5/embedding_lookup}} = ResourceGather[Tindices=DT_INT32, dtype=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ItemsEmbedding_5/embeddings, ItemsEmbedding_5/Cast)]]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Getting issue while executing :-
model.fit([train.visitorid, train.itemid], train.event, epochs=50)